# Calculating consumed energy using InfluxDB Flux statement

Tags: influxdb, flux

I am recording power meter measurements in our house which is equipped with a solar power station using a Shelly 3em. I have data from 3 phases, where one phase is the sum signal of power consumed from our energy provider and the power produced by the solar panels. The power readings have a period of 5 seconds.

I store the data in an InfluxDB and visualize using Grafana. Using Flux syntax, I can sum up the power readings to a net power reading:

```
from(bucket: "power")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "shelly_em3_main")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "power1" or r["_field"] == "power2" or r["_field"] == "power3")
    |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value") 
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r.power1 + r.power2 + r.power3}))
    |> drop(columns: ["power1", "power2","power3"])
    |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: true)
    |> yield(name: "mean")
```

[image]

As you see, there are periods where we consume power from our provider (positive values) and those where our solar panels produce more power than we consume (negative values).

Now... I want to know how much we consume and how much we give away to the grid. Hence, I need two flux statements something like this (here the "consumption statement"):

```
from(bucket: "Stromverbrauch")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "shelly_em3_main")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "power1" or r["_field"] == "power2" or r["_field"] == "power3")
  |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r.power1 + r.power2 + r.power3}))
  |> drop(columns: ["power1", "power2","power3"])
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: if r._value > 0.0 then r._value else 0.0}))
  |> integral(unit: v.windowPeriod)
  |> yield()
```

The value of this statement should have the unit "Watt hours" (I integrate over the time). However, the values this statement spits out are not realistic. For the window shown here, I get about 181000 (Watt hours?) which is not realistic at all. By "eye measurement" I get roughly 3 kWh consumption in the given graph. What would be the proper statement?